# Wpf custom user control mouseleftButtonDown capture area

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a custom control with an event handler when you click on it. Everything works and the event get fired right.

```
    AddHandler (cu.MouseLeftButtonDown), AddressOf Me.DoSomething
```

When the control resizes to show some extra information it expands. It also collapses when the user preses a button. This works alright. But now when I click where the expanded area used to be, it still fires mouse leftbuttondown on that control. I have tried to set IsHitTestVisible to false on the expanded element but it diden't work. Here's some xaml...

```
 <UserControl x:Class="MyCustomControl">
     <StackPanel>
       <Grid>
          'Stuff thats always visible
       </Grid>
    <Border IsHitTestVisible="False"   Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="left" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="top" x:Name="overView" Background="#EEEEEE" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="-325,-95,0,0" Width="auto" Height="auto" Padding="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="#999999" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3">
        <Border IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="myBorder" Margin="1" Width="300" Height="225" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#999999" Background="#DDDDDD" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Rectangle IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="rtgOverView">
            </Rectangle>
        </Border>
    </Border>
   </StackPanel>
 </UserControl>
```

The overview becomes visible when I use this code

```
  overView.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
```

And hides when I use this

```
  OverView.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
```

I fill the rectangle with a visualbrush. This happens when the control is loaded.

```
   rtgOverView.Fill = visual
```

The overView gets positioned in code behind like this

```
    If x > 350 Then
        overView.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
        overView.Margin = New Thickness(-325, -95, 0, 0)
    Else
        overView.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right
        overView.Margin = New Thickness(0, -95, -300, 0)
    End If
```

I cant use another element around my customcontrol since I also use this MouseLeftButtonDown on all different kind of controls.
I can't figure out how the boundaries on the cu.MouseLeftButtonDown event work to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was something weird going on with the size of the stackpanel. It's like the auto property doesn't size it smaller. I managed to fix it like this. When the mouse enters I put:

```
 layoutroot.ClipToBounds = False
```

This allows me to show content outside the control. 
When the mouse leaves I use:

```
 layoutroot.ClipToBounds = True
```

The clip to bound's somehow forces the StackPanel to size smaller.